# É possível o Selenium reutilizar uma sessão aberta manualmente?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

A ideia é abrir um browser qualquer (Chrome, Firefox, Opera...) por qualquer meio que seja (linha de comando, por exemplo) com exceção do próprio Selenium. E, depois, conectar o Selenium com essa sessão que existia antes dele e que não foi aberta por um outro script Selenium.

Existe uma [pergunta exatamente igual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session) no SO original. Mas todas as respostas incluem algo desse tipo:

```py
url = driver.command_executor._url       #"http://127.0.0.1:60622/hub"
session_id = driver.session_id           #'4e167f26-dc1d-4f51-a207-f761eaf73c31'

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url,desired_capabilities={})
driver.session_id = session_id
```

(Resposta do [@Manoj Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3345300/manoj-sahu) na pergunta que referenciei anteriormente)

Eu tentei e essa reposta realmente funciona, mas com um porém. É necessário obter as variáveis `url` e `session_id` de um webdriver instanciado pelo Selenium. A ideia da minha pergunta (e tinha entendido que a da pergunta original também) era reusar uma sessão que não foi criada pelo Selenium.

A pergunta antes de tudo é: Isso é possível?

Comment: resumidamente não é possível, é uma solicitação antiga mas que foi marcada pelos desenvolvedores do projeto como não factível https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18

Answer (score -3):

Você pode utilizar o add_cookie.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.add_cookie({"name": "foo1", "value": "value", 'sameSite': 'Lax'})
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
```

Capture o cookie depois de acessar a página para utilizar depois em outro acesso.
Veja a [documentação](https://www.selenium.dev/pt-br/documentation/webdriver/interactions/cookies/)